# добавить отступы в слайдере

Tags: javascript, html, css

добавить отступы в слайдере.

что есть сейчас https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYJOp.jpg

что должно получиться https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCK3w.jpg

```js
let sliderLineTwo = document.querySelector('.slider__line__two');

let twoArrowRigth = document.querySelector('.two__arrow__right');

let sliderItem = document.querySelector('.slider__card__wrapper');

let offsetTwo = 0;

twoArrowRigth.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sliderLineTwo.style.left = 0 + 'px';
  offsetTwo = offsetTwo + sliderItem.offsetWidth;
  sliderLineTwo.style.left = -offsetTwo + 'px';
  if (offsetTwo > sliderItem.offsetWidth * 2) {
    sliderLineTwo.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    offsetTwo = 0;
  }
  console.log(offsetTwo);
})
```

```css
.img__bot {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -400px;
}

.wrapper__two__section {
  position: relative;
  top: -350px;
}

.title__slider__main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.two__stroke {
  left: 15%;
}

.two__title {
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}

.link__slider__up {
  width: 273px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
}

.link__slider__up__active {
  background-image: url(../img/stroke__text.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.text__slider__up {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'IntroRustH2-Base';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F0AE64;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text__slider__up__active {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.row__slider {
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.slider__two {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1110px;
  height: 600px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider__line__two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 5000px;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

.slider__card__wrapper {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 60px rgba(48, 171, 119, 0.15);
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 508px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider__title {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 167%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #103D2A;
  font-family: 'IntroRustH2-Base';
}

.price__slider {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 229%;
  text-align: center;
  font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
  color: #103D2A;
}

.price__slider span {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 133%;
  text-align: center;
  font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
  color: #103D2A;
}

.two__arrow,
.two__arrow__right {
  top: 500px;
}

.two__arrow {
  left: -100px;
}

.two__arrow__right {
  right: -100px;
}

.two__section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img__slider {
  width: 182px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper__two__section">
  <section class="section two__section">
    <div class="title__slider__main">
      <h1 class="title two__title">Разнообразие вариантов:<br>от стандартных до элитных моделей
        <img class="stroke two__stroke" src="img/stroke.png" alt="строке">
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row row__slider">
      <div class="link__slider__up">
        <p class="text__slider__up">товары</p>
      </div>
      <div class="link__slider__up two__link">
        <p class="text__slider__up two__text__slider">наборы</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__two">
      <div class="slider__line__two">
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="img/slider__had1.png" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="img/slider__had1.png" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="img/slider__had1.png" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="https://placepic.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Grizzly-Bear-full-HD.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1930013/pub_5e1894ebaad43600ae414732_5e199c4798fe7900b031ac74/scale_1200" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow two__arrow">
      <div class="wrapper__arrow">
        <img class="arrow__icon" src="img/arrow.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow__right two__arrow__right">
      <div class="wrapper__arrow">
        <img class="arrow__icon right__icon" src="img/arrow.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: чем вас margin не устраивает? Можно еще на grid переделать, и там grid-gap использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил свойство `gap`

```css
.slider__line__two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 5000px;
  gap: 40px;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
```

```js
let sliderLineTwo = document.querySelector('.slider__line__two');

let twoArrowRigth = document.querySelector('.two__arrow__right');

let sliderItem = document.querySelector('.slider__card__wrapper');

let offsetTwo = 0;

twoArrowRigth.addEventListener('click', function() {
  sliderLineTwo.style.left = 0 + 'px';
  offsetTwo = offsetTwo + sliderItem.offsetWidth;
  sliderLineTwo.style.left = -offsetTwo + 'px';
  if (offsetTwo > sliderItem.offsetWidth * 2) {
    sliderLineTwo.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    offsetTwo = 0;
  }
  console.log(offsetTwo);
})
```

```css
.img__bot {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -400px;
}

.wrapper__two__section {
  position: relative;
  top: -350px;
}

.title__slider__main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.two__stroke {
  left: 15%;
}

.two__title {
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}

.link__slider__up {
  width: 273px;
  height: 75px;
  position: relative;
}

.link__slider__up__active {
  background-image: url(../img/stroke__text.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.text__slider__up {
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'IntroRustH2-Base';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 62px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F0AE64;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: fit-content;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text__slider__up__active {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.row__slider {
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.slider__two {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1110px;
  height: 600px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider__line__two {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 5000px;
  gap: 40px;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}

.slider__card__wrapper {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 60px rgba(48, 171, 119, 0.15);
  border-radius: 24px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 508px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider__title {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 167%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #103D2A;
  font-family: 'IntroRustH2-Base';
}

.price__slider {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 229%;
  text-align: center;
  font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
  color: #103D2A;
}

.price__slider span {
  font-family: Raleway;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 133%;
  text-align: center;
  font-feature-settings: 'pnum' on, 'lnum' on;
  color: #103D2A;
}

.two__arrow,
.two__arrow__right {
  top: 500px;
}

.two__arrow {
  left: -100px;
}

.two__arrow__right {
  right: -100px;
}

.two__section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img__slider {
  width: 182px;
  height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper__two__section">
  <section class="section two__section">
    <div class="title__slider__main">
      <h1 class="title two__title">Разнообразие вариантов:<br>от стандартных до элитных моделей
        <img class="stroke two__stroke" src="img/stroke.png" alt="строке">
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row row__slider">
      <div class="link__slider__up">
        <p class="text__slider__up">товары</p>
      </div>
      <div class="link__slider__up two__link">
        <p class="text__slider__up two__text__slider">наборы</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__two">
      <div class="slider__line__two">
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="img/slider__had1.png" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="img/slider__had1.png" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="img/slider__had1.png" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="https://placepic.ru/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/Grizzly-Bear-full-HD.jpg" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
        <div class="slider__card__wrapper">
          <p class="slider__title">банная шапка-колпак</p>
          <img class="img__slider" src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/1930013/pub_5e1894ebaad43600ae414732_5e199c4798fe7900b031ac74/scale_1200" alt="">
          <p class="price__slider">от <span>100</span> руб/шт</p>
          <button class="btn__main">
                                    <img class="btn__img" src="img/btn1.png" alt="">
                                    <img class="btn__img2" src="img/btn2.png" alt="">
                                    <p class="main__btn__text">примерить ваш логотип</p></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow two__arrow">
      <div class="wrapper__arrow">
        <img class="arrow__icon" src="img/arrow.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow__right two__arrow__right">
      <div class="wrapper__arrow">
        <img class="arrow__icon right__icon" src="img/arrow.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто отступы элементов друг от друга

```
.slider__card__wrapper{
margin:20px;
}
```

либо

```
.slider__line__two{
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
justify-content:center;
}
```

Второй вариант равномерно распределяет элементы слайдера внетри контейнера по горизонтали

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]